# isp overriding netbios

Tags: networking, nat, netbios

I have a Thomson TG789vn v2 router and a weird way ISP (ASK4, UK) wants me to use it.

They are telling me to connect their cable to Ethernet 1 slot and disable DHCP on the router.

When I do that some magic happens and the router no longer shows up in my Ethernet connection details, instead there is a **10.x.x.x** address, I can no longer access neither the router nor the network share I had on it, when I try to ping either of those I am getting a "Destination host could not be reached" reply *from the 10.x.x.x gateway*. ISP also requires to register every newly connected device under my account on their portal.

When I plug their cable into the WAN port I end up on an error page on their webserver when I try any kind of connection.

So how do I go about it to have my network share working?

Comment: What hardware does the ISP provide you? What is the device you'd be connecting to your router?

Comment: ISP does not provide me with anything. I'm connecting a laptop, and a couple smartphones.

Comment: If the ISP doesn't provide you anything, what are you connecting to your router?!

Comment: Ethernet socket in the wall <-> eth cable <-> router <-> my devices

Comment: Ahh, are you in a building or something with shared Internet? What does the cable come from?

Comment: Yes, correct. Cable is simple Ethernet RJ45 which I had a bunch of, the only thing I have from ISP is the Ethernet socket in the wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ISP is suggesting you use your router only as a switch. This would make sense if they already provided you a router. You don't want two routers in the same network as this causes problems with double-NAT.

You need to assign the router an IP address that's valid in the LAN range that your existing router provides (ideally outside of its DHCP range). You need to get a new IP address and default gateway on your PC as well.

You can usually figure this out by trial and error. For example, if a PC connected directly to your ISP gets assigned an IP address of `192.168.1.101` and a default gateway of `192.168.1.1`, you can determine that the ISP's router has an IP address of `192.168.1.1` and its DHCP block probably starts with `192.168.1.100`. That would make `192.168.1.2` a good LAN IP address for your router.

Comment: What about setting obtain via DHCP option on router?

Comment: If the router has an option to obtain its *LAN* IP by DHCP, then use that. But usually that option is for the WAN IP. Since you're not connecting this router to a WAN, that won't help you.

Comment: The router web interface certainly does not allow me to set up an IP address for it let alone by DHCP and I have no clue how to do this via telnet.

Comment: It [can be done](http://forums.modem-help.co.uk/viewtopic.php?t=9243) but it's a real pain. You may just want to get a different router -- ideally one that can run something like Tomato or OpenWRT.

Comment: One should absolutely not "make up" (or guess or anything else) IP addresses on a network he does not administer! Either tweak your device to get an address assigned over DHCP (or whatever protocol the ISP uses, usually it is DHCP), or ask your ISP for an address some other way. Oh, you did exactly that, I see in your own answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Got it running finally :)

Steps were:
 **1**. Register both router and smb MAC addresses with ISP through their
    web front end
 **2**. Disconnect from the ISP
 **3**. telnet into router

```
ip arpadd intf=LocalNetwork ip=<smb address supplied by isp> hwaddr=<smb share mac>
ip ipadd intf=LocalNetwork addr=<router address supplied by isp> netmask=<netmask supplied by isp>
saveall
```

The setup I have is a slightly modified Bridge template from [MH Setup Wizards](http://forums.modem-help.co.uk/viewtopic.php?t=9301). Don't forget to enable USB controller if you have just installed the template:

```
pwr config usb-controller=enabled
```